# Adding more boxes to fill

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $to = "receiver@domain.com"; // this is IT Support Email address
        $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // sender's first name
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // sender's last name
        $subject = "Form submission"; // Email confirmation submission 
        from sender
        $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission"; // Email confirmation submission 
        from receiver
        $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " requested:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message']; // Email header 
        $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

        $headers = "From:" . $from;
        $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        mail($from, $subject2, $message2, $headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
        echo "Request Submitted Succesfully. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will 
        fulfill your request shortly.";
        // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to 
        another page.
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Device and Set Up Request Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I add more labels below the message for the users to fill? For example, right after "Message:," I want to add "Supervisor name" and more labels. In addition, those labels not only appear on the website, but also is wrapped and get emailed to the receiver.

Comment: you copy just like first_name code.